# Loop through a list of lists to find max value

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

The following shows a sample of a list of lists that I have:

```
[[['point_5', [5, 6, 7, 8], 11.0],
['point_5', [6, 7, 8, 9],12.57]],
[['point_18', [3, 4, 5, 6],6.25],
['point_18', [3, 5, 6, 7],7.2],
['point_18', [4, 5, 6, 7],7.55],
['point_18', [6, 7, 8, 9],14.0],
['point_19', [3, 5, 6, 7],8.166],
['point_19', [5, 6, 7, 8],9.285],
['point_19', [6, 7, 8, 9],11.0]]]
```

I need to define a loop which searches through each element of this list of lists and returns the maximum value of the last element of each list. What I mean is that for example for `[6,7,8,9]` we have:

```
['point_5', [6, 7, 8, 9], 12.57]
['point_18', [6, 7, 8, 9],14.0]
['point_19', [6, 7, 8, 9],11.0]
```

Since `max(12.57,14.0,11.0) = 14.0` then what I am looking for is a list that one of its element is `[point_18,[6,7,8,9],14.0]`.

Another example is that since the only element that has `[3, 4, 5, 6]` is `['point_18', [3, 4, 5, 6],6.25]` then another element of the new list should be `[point_18,[3,4,5,6],6.25]`.

In fact, the new list of lists that I am trying to create should be like the following list:

```
New_list = [['point_5',[5,6,7,8],11.0],['point_18',[6,7,8,9],14.0],['point_18', [3, 4, 5, 6],6.25],['point_19', [3, 5, 6, 7],8.166],['point_18', [4, 5, 6, 7],7.55]].
```

I am not sure if it is a good idea or not but what I have done is that first I tried to extract each unique [x,y,i,j] in a list through the following code:

```
A = []
for i in bob:
    for j in i:
        A.append(j[1])
import itertools
A.sort()
B = list(A for A,_ in itertools.groupby(A))
```

Now B is:

```
[[3, 4, 5, 6],
 [3, 5, 6, 7],
 [4, 5, 6, 7],
 [5, 6, 7, 8],
 [6, 7, 8, 9]]
```

Then I want to search for each element of this list in the main lists of list and find the max value.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please post your own attempt.  See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Stack Overflow is not a coding service.  You might consider a PANDAS df and `groupby`, or a list comprehension that filters on the first field (to get the same result).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I think you can try breaking the problems into parts.**

**I don't know if you had a list that already done the first step, so I am assuming no**

This is the list that I am working with:

```
your_list = [['point_5', [5, 6, 7, 8], 11.0],
            ['point_5', [6, 7, 8, 9],12.57],
            ['point_18', [3, 4, 5, 6],6.25],
            ['point_18', [3, 5, 6, 7],7.2],
            ['point_18', [4, 5, 6, 7],7.55],
            ['point_18', [6, 7, 8, 9],14.0],
            ['point_19', [3, 5, 6, 7],8.166],
            ['point_19', [5, 6, 7, 8],9.285],
            ['point_19', [6, 7, 8, 9],11.0]]
```

First, try sorting the list in a dict.

```
sorted_dict = {}
for i in your_list:
    if tuple(i[1]) in sorted_dict:
        sorted_dict[tuple(i[1])].append(i)
    else:
       sorted_dict[tuple(i[1])] = [i]
```

Then, select the max and put it in a list.

```
return_list = []
for key, values in sorted_dict.items():
    print(values)
    return_list.append(sorted(values, key=lambda x: float(x[2]))[-1]) # sort the list according to the third value
```

Return list now should have the value you're looking for

I am not sure if this is what you're looking for so comment if there's any problem